# C - IPv6 raw ICMPv6 packet crafting

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6, icmp

I am currently trying to create raw ICMPv6 packet in C. I only found IPv4 examples that works well and I don't see what I do wrong with IPv6.

**What I know so far :**

- I looked over an old [mailing-list post](http://www.linux-ipv6.org/ml/usagi-users/msg02249.html) to discover I needed to set some variables in in6_addr (→ error 22), but besides they are using :

  ```
  sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
  ```
- On the [BCP38 project](http://spoofer.cmand.org/software.php), they use LIBNET apparently. I prefer avoid librairies if I can do with sockets. In that case, how the calls are made to the "networking API" if not through socket.h.
- I read [here](http://www.pdbuchan.com/rawsock/rawsock.html) that **IP_HDRINCL** has no equivalent in IPv6. (but why ?)

The following code, is sending an ICMPv6 packet probably due to IPPROTO_ICMPV6 but with kernel-added headers and quite bad packet content... (with a wrong destination address, I didn't fix yet some endianness issue). It worked in IPv6.
When I use IPPROTO_RAW, the packet is simply not sent...

Any idea ? Thanks in advance

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip6.h>
#include <netinet/icmp6.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct ipv6header {
    unsigned char priority:4, version:4;
    unsigned char flow[3];
    unsigned short int length;
    unsigned char nexthdr;
    unsigned char hoplimit;

    unsigned int saddr[4];
    unsigned int daddr[4];
};

struct icmpv6header {
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned char code;
    unsigned short int chk_sum;
    unsigned int body; 
};

int main()
{
    char* packet = (char*) malloc(sizeof(struct ipv6header)+sizeof(struct icmpv6header));
    struct ipv6header* ip = (struct ipv6header*) packet;
    struct icmpv6header* icmp = (struct icmpv6header*) (packet+sizeof(struct ipv6header));

    icmp->type = 128;
    icmp->code = 0;
    icmp->chk_sum = (0x6a13);
    icmp->body = htonl(1234);

    ip->version = 6;
    ip->priority = 0;
    (ip->flow)[0] = 0;
    (ip->flow)[1] = 0;
    (ip->flow)[2] = 0;
    ip->length = ((unsigned short int) sizeof(struct icmpv6header));
    ip->nexthdr = 58;
    ip->hoplimit = 255;

    struct sockaddr_in6 remote;
    remote.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    remote.sin6_port = 0;
    remote.sin6_flowinfo = 0;
    remote.sin6_scope_id = 0;

    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:470:x:x:y:y:y:dd7b", &(remote.sin6_addr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:470:x:x:bee:bee:bee:bee", &(ip->saddr));
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:470:x:x:y:y:y:dd7b", &(ip->daddr));

    int sock, optval;
    sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);
    if(sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Error setting socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    int ret = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IP_HDRINCL, &optval, sizeof(int));
    if(ret != 0) {
        printf("Error setting options %d\n", ret);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket options done\n");

    int ret = sendto(sock, packet, ip->length, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, sizeof(remote));

    if(ret != ip->length) {
        printf("Packet not sent : %d (%d)\n",ret,errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Packet sent\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two tips (but unrelated to your problems): First don't use compiler-defined types like `char`, `short int` or `int`. Use `int8_t`, `int16_t`, and `int32_t` (or their unsigned variants) from the [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) header file. Secondly, [in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Are you root when executing this program? Can you post the output of `sudo strace program` ?

Comment: Thanks for theses advices. I was running root. strace allowed me to see that the length was shorter than expected ! Thanks.
Corrected also the types and the cast.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue and solved it by using `IPV6_HDRINCL` instead of `IP_HDRINCL`. when setting the socket options.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after few code rewrites I succeeded :
the main problem was, the packet was truncated due to a bad length when I used `IPPROTO_RAW`. As a result, the system discarded it before it could reach the network.
I also changed

```
uint16_t daddr[8];
```

and

```
uint16_t ipdst[8] = {htons(0x2001),htons(0x470),htons(x),htons(x),htons(y),htons(y),htons(y),htons(0xdd7b)};
uint16_t ipsrc[8] = {htons(0x2001),htons(0x470),htons(x),htons(x),htons(0xbee),htons(0xbee),htons(0xbee),htons(0xbee)};

int j = 0;
for(j=0;j<=7;j++) {
    remote.sin6_addr.s6_addr16[j]=ipdst[j];
    ip->saddr[j]=ipsrc[j];
    ip->daddr[j]=ipdst[j];
}
```

Thanks !